# Compounds that Liberate Hydrogen from Water, Reversibly

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, thermodynamics, hydrogen

I'm working on a paper which provides an overview of all the current methods for storing hydrogen gas as part of a renewable energy system, and I understand compressed gas and metal hydride storage well enough. I am struggling, however, to find a table, paper, database, etc.  which compares all the compounds that could be used to liberate hydrogen gas from water.

I’m looking for a compound(s) that can be stored indefinitely at ~STP and would yield hydrogen gas in a reversible reaction with water? By reversible, I mean that with the addition of electrical or heat energy, it could be transformed back to the state it was in before it reacted with the water (and thus used to generate more hydrogen gas). Ideally, all the reagents would be low cost and abundant, but this is less important provided that the reaction is reversible. 
I am aware that this process is likely to be wildly inefficient, and that the round trip efficiency of any commercially available battery chemistry would make it a superior option for storing electrical energy. In the context of a broader application, however, this system could afford to have huge energetic losses in exchange for providing what is in effect a "stockpile" of hydrogen with virtually no storage cost.

If this information does not exist in an aggregated form(s), how would I go about hiring an individual or institution to compile it? Very grateful for any thoughts the community has on this subject.